# Is it possible debug 32 bit userspace and 64 bit linux kernel space with the same gdb on qemu simultaneously?

Tags: gdb, arm, qemu, arm64

Currently i have 64-bit linux kernel and some 32 bit proccess e.g. '/system/bin/app_process32' which i want to debug. After returning from kernel space with asm instruction 'eret' to 64 bit application - i can debug it without any problem. But if 'eret' instruction returned to 32 bit application - gdb doesn't work - i can't debug it. Is it some limitation of gdb and how can i fix it?

Comment: can we have the gdb error msg if any?

Comment: @Jeffrey No any errors, just msg: "Cannot access memory at address"